# When to initialize an array with 256

Tags: java, c++, arrays

I was looking through the cracking the coding interview book solutions and noticed the following problem:

Implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters. What if you can not use additional data structures?

This was one of the solutions provided:

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars2(String str) {
  boolean[] char_set = new boolean[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      int val = str.charAt(i);
      if (char_set[val]) return false;
      char_set[val] = true;
    }
   return true;
 }
```

Why is the `char_set` array initialized with a size of 256? I was thinking that it was because there are 128 ascii characters but I'm not sure. Also, this solution seems to be in Java, but would an initial size also be necessary if this was done in C++?

Comment: Your code only works if the only valid values are 8 bits. Because 2^8 is 256.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can you provide examples of characters that might not be valid?

Comment: Something like `` might be an issue.

Comment: This just have to be a very bad conversion of a C function, because Java uses Unicode, and there are about 120000 official valid characters as of version 8, and more than 1.1 million possible code points. **Fail**

Comment: As the other comment suggested, there are thousands of data points possible.  The *real* solution is to use a map, not an array (or use an array in a map-like fashion).  The solution you posted is naive, at best.

Comment: `What if you can not use additional data structures?`  The question is asking to dumb yourself down and use the most naive approach, instead of engaging you in identifying what the appropriate data structure would be.  I see no benefit in a question that says this.

Comment: Further, an array *is* a datastructure...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, this would be the 'naive' or first approach used in an interview

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I was thinking that it was because there are 128 ascii characters but I'm not sure.

No. With extended ASCII codes, there are a total 256 characters. That's the reason for 256.

http://www.asciitable.com/

Apart from the reason given for `256`, please note that com/

Note that as Erwin Bolwidt said, *the code is at best incomplete in any case, because Java "characters" are not ASCII nor extended ASCII. They are "a 16-bit Unicode character", so the array should have been new boolean[65536]*

Comment: Would you need to initialize it this way if the solution was done in C++?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 I'm not a C++ guru but, it seems yes, you need to give the length while declaring the array itself.

Comment: But the code is at best incomplete in any case, because Java "characters" are not ASCII nor extended ASCII. They are "a 16-bit Unicode character", so the array should have been `new boolean[65536]`.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Correct, and with surrogate pairs you have even more code points than that.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt True. Added your comment

Comment: It seems you just converted your C++ code to Java code. But hava char is  is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

Comment: @Andres at least you don't get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` this way. I doubt that the definition from the JLS is valid ("The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character."), they should have specified something that exists such as UTF-16, UCS-2 or UCS-4.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2^8 = 256 chars in an extended ASCII char set.

Check it here. http://www.ascii-code.com/

Solution is telling you about 1's and 0's can be only two values. That's why it is using a primitive value array of boolean. Without initialization boolean variable is always FALSE.

C++ allows

```
bool arr[256] = {};
```

a good example for arrays:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
bool test1[16] = { false };
bool test2[16] = { true };
bool test3[16];

cout << "Test1 - Init to false" << endl;
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(test1)/sizeof(test1[0]); ++i)
    cout << test1[i];

cout << endl << "Test2 - Init to true" << endl;
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(test2)/sizeof(test2[0]); ++i)
    cout << test2[i];

cout << endl << "Test3 - Uninitialized" << endl;
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(test3)/sizeof(test3[0]); ++i)
    cout << test3[i];

cout << endl;
}
```

and gives results as :

```
Test1 - Init to false
0000000000000000
Test2 - Init to true
1000000000000000
Test3 - Uninitialized
12024619195255127009671929525512700
```

Answer (score 1):

Btw the code is in Java.

```
boolean[] char_set = new boolean[256]
```

would be

```
bool* char_set = new bool[256]
```

in C++

Answer (score 0):

Another way is the Brute Force, but it's not the optimal solution.

You can use two for loop where outer loop

```
for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
```

and the inner loop would be like

```
for(int j=i+1; j<str.length(); j++)
```

Comparison of both the value will lead to answer

```
if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j))
```

Also, You can go with checking the alphabets, If there is a limitation for checking only 26 english alphabets small a to z or capital A to Z

Answer (score 0):

Number of extended ASCII codes, there are a total 256 characters , So only we are taking 256

This is one of the solutions related to :

```
    class Solution {
    public boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
       
       if(s.length() != t.length()) return false;

       int[] arr = new int[256];

       for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
           arr[s.charAt(i)]++;
           arr[t.charAt(i)]--;
       }

       for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
           if(arr[i]!=0){
               return false;
           }
       }
       return true;
    }
}
```